# Why is vue not showing content and state of objects in the list?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a crud app in vue. Currently it seems to create, edit and delete objects fine. But it's not showing content and reflecting state of added/existing objects. Editing items multiple times is also acting weirdly. Can you help me understand why? How can I display content correctly?

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '\
              <li>\
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked" />\
                <button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">Delete</button>\
                <button v-on:click="$emit(\'edit\')">Edit</button>\
                {{ content }}\
              </li>\
            ',
  props: ['content', 'isChecked']
})
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    "todo": {
      isChecked: true
    },
    "todos": [{
        id: 1,
        isChecked: true,
        content: "hahaha"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isChecked: false,
        content: "hohoho"
      }
    ],
    "counter": 3
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTodo: function() {
      if (this.todo.id != undefined) {
        this.todos.filter(t => t.id === this.todo.id).content = this.todo.content;
        this.todos.filter(t => t.id === this.todo.id).content = this.todo.isChecked;
      } else {
        this.todos.push({
          id: this.counter++,
          content: this.todo.content,
          isChecked: this.todo.isChecked
        })
      }
      this.clear();
    },
    edit: function(todo) {
      this.todo = todo;
      console.log(todo);
    },
    clear: function() {
      this.todo.content = '';
      this.todo.isChecked = true;
      this.todo.id = undefined;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="todo.isChecked" />
    <label for="checkbox">Done</label>
    <input v-model="todo.content" placeholder="edit me" />
    <button type="button" @click="clear">Clear</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li is="todo-item" v-for="(todo, index) in todos" v-bind:key="todo.id" v-bind:title="todo.content" v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)" v-on:edit="edit(todo)"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is because you are passing data from the parent to the `todo-item` as a prop, and you are mutating the prop—you receive console warnings for trying to do so (check your code snippet and you'll see them logged). Mutating the prop does not change the parent state (updated data does not flow upwards back to the parent).

Comment: I don't see any console warnings. What is the correct way to do it? Can you direct me to some documentation?